Fresh development environment fails to install required packages (NextJS/Typescript Env)
Im setting up a standard env for Solana using NextJS/Typescript. When I try to add standard packages via Yarn:
yarn add @solana/wallet-adapter-react @solana/wallet-adapter-wallets @solana/web3.js @solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui

I then get multiple errors. Is this NextJS version related?

YN0002: │ @fractalwagmi/solana-wallet-adapter@npm:0.1.1 doesn't provide react (p30917), requested by @fractalwagmi/popup-connection
➤ YN0002: │ @fractalwagmi/solana-wallet-adapter@npm:0.1.1 doesn't provide react-dom (p5ab68), requested by @fractalwagmi/popup-connection
➤ YN0002: │ @solana-mobile/mobile-wallet-adapter-protocol-web3js@npm:2.1.3 [92141] doesn't provide react-native (p1b5b4), requested by @solana-mobile/mobile-wallet-adapter-protocol
➤ YN0002: │ @solana-mobile/wallet-adapter-mobile@npm:2.1.3 [93ed9] doesn't provide react-native (p55c0e), requested by @react-native-async-storage/async-storage
➤ YN0002: │ @solana/codecs@npm:2.0.0-preview.2 doesn't provide fastestsmallesttextencoderdecoder (p36ecc), requested by @solana/codecs-strings
➤ YN0002: │ @solana/wallet-adapter-particle@npm:0.1.12 [f33ed] doesn't provide bs58 (pc9a54), requested by @particle-network/solana-wallet
➤ YN0002: │ @solana/wallet-adapter-torus@npm:0.11.28 [f33ed] doesn't provide @babel/runtime (p5d8fb), requested by @toruslabs/solana-embed
➤ YN0002: │ @solana/wallet-adapter-trezor@npm:0.1.2 [f33ed] doesn't provide tslib (p7b33e), requested by @trezor/connect-web
➤ YN0002: │ @solana/wallet-standard-wallet-adapter-react@npm:1.1.2 [390ff] doesn't provide @solana/web3.js (p7b132), requested by @solana/wallet-standard-wallet-adapter-base
➤ YN0002: │ @solana/wallet-standard-wallet-adapter-react@npm:1.1.2 [390ff] doesn't provide bs58 (p9660b), requested by @solana/wallet-standard-wallet-adapter-base
➤ YN0002: │ @solana/wallet-standard-wallet-adapter-react@npm:1.1.2 [93ed9] doesn't provide @solana/web3.js (pe0ae3), requested by @solana/wallet-standard-wallet-adapter-base
➤ YN0002: │ @solana/wallet-standard-wallet-adapter-react@npm:1.1.2 [93ed9] doesn't provide bs58 (pc3263), requested by @solana/wallet-standard-wallet-adapter-base
➤ YN0002: │ @solana/wallet-standard-wallet-adapter@npm:1.1.2 doesn't provide @solana/wallet-adapter-base (p3d0d5), requested by @solana/wallet-standard-wallet-adapter-react
➤ YN0002: │ @solana/wallet-standard-wallet-adapter@npm:1.1.2 doesn't provide @solana/web3.js (pf9cc5), requested by @solana/wallet-standard-wallet-adapter-base
➤ YN0002: │ @solana/wallet-standard-wallet-adapter@npm:1.1.2 doesn't provide bs58 (p8299b), requested by @solana/wallet-standard-wallet-adapter-base
➤ YN0002: │ @solana/wallet-standard-wallet-adapter@npm:1.1.2 doesn't provide react (pba057), requested by @solana/wallet-standard-wallet-adapter-react
➤ YN0002: │ @trezor/connect@npm:9.2.2 [23d23] doesn't provide @babel/core (p50b41), requested by @babel/preset-typescript
➤ YN0002: │ @trezor/env-utils@npm:1.0.15 [cafdf] doesn't provide expo (p40e5a), requested by expo-constants
➤ YN0000: │ Some peer dependencies are incorrectly met; run yarn explain peer-requirements  for details, where  is the six-letter p-prefixed code


It looks like you might be missing some dependencies. According to https://github.com/anza-xyz/wallet-adapter/blob/master/APP.md#quick-setup-using-react-ui, you should run:
yarn add \
    @solana/wallet-adapter-base \
    @solana/wallet-adapter-react \
    @solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui \
    @solana/wallet-adapter-wallets \
    @solana/web3.js \
    react


Did this of course and same result. Except for react as that is built into nextjs. I do know it is a dependancy issue the question is why is Yarn responding in this way? nothing out of the ordinary in my setup.
